# Spring Frame Work, calling method from JSP without reloading or loading page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am new to spring. I have a jsp project that does multiple things. Each button click is associated with a method (addMoney, selectItem, confirm, etc). I want to call these java methods using Spring, without reloading the page after each call. Is this possible? If it's impossible, what is the best practice to return every variable needed in the JSP in the model *every* time? That is how I am handling it now, and my controller methods look all the same, except for one or two lines. Ex below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuarter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addQuarter(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    service.addQuarter();
    List<Item> itemList = service.getAllItems();
    model.addAttribute("itemList", itemList);
    model.addAttribute("change", service.displayCurrency());
    model.addAttribute("message", "Quarter added");
    model.addAttribute("changeDisplay", "");
    model.addAttribute("selectedItem", service.selectItemById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))));
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addDime", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addQDime(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    service.addDime();
    List<Item> itemList = service.getAllItems();
    model.addAttribute("itemList", itemList);
    model.addAttribute("change", service.displayCurrency());
    model.addAttribute("message", "Dime added");
    model.addAttribute("changeDisplay", "");
    model.addAttribute("selectedItem", service.selectItemById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))));
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: try to use ajax call

Answer (score -1):

The methods in your `@Controller` returns a page with the information in model that can be used in the jsp this is resolved in server side and return html to browser.

If you want to modify you page without reload complete you page you must use `AJAX`, for this your methods in the `@Controller` must change and respond the information in the body of the message for example as a JSON.

Example:

`@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addQuarter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Item> addQuarter(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        service.addQuarter();
        List<Item> itemList = service.getAllItems();
        return itemList;
    }`

[Here is a good tutorial spring-4-mvc-ajax](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/)